# Prioritize visible content | Google page speed insight

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-pagespeed

I have tested my website in google page speed insight and there several errors and warning. One of them is **Prioritize visible content.** I think reason behind this warning is a javascript code to fit header image. Following snippet I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resize () {
        var heights = window.innerHeight;
        document.getElementById("fill-screen1").style.height = heights + "px";
        document.getElementById("fill-screen2").style.height = heights + "px";
    }
    resize();
    window.onresize = function() {
        resize();
    };
</script>
```

**It is a bootstrap carousel.**

Is there any way to remove this warning??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This docs page should answer your question.
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/PrioritizeVisibleContent

> This rule triggers when PageSpeed Insights detects that additional network round trips are required to render the above the fold content of the page.

"Above the Fold" is a web design term meaning what the user first sees, if you didn't know. Your goal should be to minimize the time from request to full load. If says in the doc that you can do a couple of things. You can minifiy your CSS. If you are loading images from external sources, consider using CSS/SVG instead. You can also try putting stuff like third-party widgets a little bit further down the page. It also says that you could load the article before the sidebar, if you have a site layout like that.

I think your problem could be the carousel. If it includes images, try just using text, or put the carousel below what the user first sees. Also, you may want to load external CSS and JS after you load your HTML. Always load CSS before JS, too.

Comment: Here is my report [link](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zubizi.com%2F&tab=desktop) . Actually when i am clicking on "see screenshot" there is showing blank white screen with a button and header and the background image is not showing.